# Pasar dos variables desde el evento onclick a mi Controller ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Estoy utilizando el evento `onclick` de mi button para pasarle dos parámetros a mis Controller pero no se si se puede hacer esto en ASP.NET MVC

```
 onclick="location.href ='/Report/SaveReport?change=true,/Report/SaveReport?Turno=@ViewBag.turn'"
```

Lo estoy haciendo bien, ya he intentado ponerlo de varias maneras pero siempre manda el `Turno` vacío.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma de pasar dos parámetros o más al Controlador, es enviarlos en el *QueryString* separados por un **&**.

En tu caso el código sería el siguiente:

```
onclick="location.href ='/Report/SaveReport?change=true&turno=@ViewBag.turn'"
```

Y por supuesto en tu Controlador, recibirlos como parámetro en la Acción correspondiente:

```
public class ReportController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SaveReport(string change, string turno)
    {

    }
 ...
```